# Gfortran: Non-backwards compatibility

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, legacy

I have some legacy Fortran code (Several hundreds of lines long). The code works fine in older versions of GCC (6.3) at the uni, but on newer versions it returns `NaN`.

What options can I add to modern gfortran (Not installing an old version) for potentially fixing this issue.

What I've tried: `-std=legacy` and `-m32`,`-mpc32`. (Since I'm not sure whether the working compiler is 32 or 64 bits) All return `NaN` (`-m32` is also slow)

Comment: For a start, compile the code with warnings (`-Wall`) and run-time checks (`-fcheck=all`). This should help to find sources of errors. The latter option has a negative effect on performance, so to be used for debugging.

Comment: As you're getting NaN, add  -ffpe-trap=invalid to your command line.  This will show you were your code is going left.

Comment: Several hundreds of lines is quite a short code. You can also just step through with a debugger and place diagnostic print statements at strategic places.

Comment: are you using the command gfortan and what extension are you using on your code file?

Comment: No extensions used. Linux build. Ubuntu and Arch x86_64 both used.